# How can I convert a 2 digit number into hour format in R?

Tags: r, time, numbers

I have the following vector:

```r
times<-c(00, 01, 02, 03)
```

I want to have it in the following format:

```
times<-c(00:00:00, 01:00:00, 02:00:00, 03:00:00)
```

Do I have to add zeros first and then add the `:` or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: `sprintf("%02d:00:00", times)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider which **type** you want for your formatted times. Characters? Proper date-time type? This solution uses the lubridate package:

```
times<-c(00, 01, 02, 03)
parse_date_time(times, "H")
```

You also get a default date for free.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `hms` from `hms` package

```
library(hms)
hms(hour = times)
#00:00:00
#01:00:00
#02:00:00
#03:00:00
```